# Error adding a node to docker swarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, rhel7

I'm following the guide on https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/add-nodes/ to add a node after creating a swarm. I ran

```
 sudo docker swarm init --advertise-addr 35.163.93.96 --listen-addr 127.0.0.1
```

to create the swarm. Then, to try and join I ran

```
sudo docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-4h71pkxaykm2lo5pyiu0i1675dw94zwllt5p11iswyq17gkojf-14i50r7g49nh98rd3w847d7pj 
    35.163.93.96:2377
```

I keep getting the same error

```
 Error response from daemon: Timeout was reached before node was joined. The attempt to join the swarm will continue in the background. Use the "docker info" command to see the current swarm status of your node.
```

After running `sudo docker info`I see that Swarm: pending. I have looked online, (including on SO) to find a remedy to this and nothing has worked. I tried restarting the docker service and leaving the swarm on both the manager and the worker then remaking it the swarm and restarting docker in a certain order. I tried following the tutorial on Docker's official youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x843GyFRIIY&index=7&list=PLkA60AVN3hh8lmRdhPKzsNJvZxJ8dpj4t) where they demonstrated doing it with containers and that also did not work. I also noticed that other people who posted similar questions to this did not always get a response that worked. At this point I don't know what else to do.

Comment: The document looks old. What is the version of docker? Swarm has been integrated into the docker engine since docker 1.12. The document for swarm with docker 1.12 or later is here. https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/

Comment: Apologies for that, I put in the wrong link. I updated it to the one I actually used and it is just the link that you would find by following the tutorial on the link that you yourself posted.

Comment: It is OK that the link was wrong. I guess it is unnecessary to specify `--listen-addr`, is it the same when not specifying this?

Comment: Yes. I tried it several different ways and still could not get it to join. The reason I specified `--listen-addr` is because I was getting an error to specify a listening address.

Comment: As another possible factor, it seems that worker and manager cannot communicate with each other. Did you check the open ports? https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#/open-ports-between-the-hosts

Comment: I considered that. I opened up all the ports listed on that tutorial and for good measure also configured my security groups on AWS to allow those tcp  and udp rules. I still got the same error though

Comment: I'm not sure it's a network or docker problem. Starting docker daemon in debug mode may be helpful for you: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/

Comment: By the way, `35.163.93.96` looks like a global IP. Of course, depending on  your network configuration, in AWS, swarm manager and worker are usually placed in the same VPC and communicate with each other by private IP. Why are you trying to connect to swarm manager by global IP?

Comment: Yeah you are correct about that. I forgot to mark this as solved. I ended up making my own vpc on AWS CLI in order to make the swarm manager and all the nodes. Then I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use AWS CLI to make your own VPC, subnet ID, route table ID, Internet gateway ID to use for these particular machines. Then follow along with the tutorial and create the instances and assign the roles